# Strange error force:org:shape:list: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: salesforcedx, error, salesforcedx-cli, cli

Strange error force:org:shape:list:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

When I executed a command `force:org:shape:list`, I am obtaining a very strange misterious error:  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
I thought I figured it out and trying to change every sandbox configuration file in ~.sfdx folder to append `.sandbox` domain change

from

```
"https://company--d.my.salesforce.com",
```

to

```
"https://company--d.sandbox.my.salesforce.com",
```

however, this didn't work. What is going on?

Comment: Can you confirm on which instance does the sandbox  which does not have .sandbox lies?

Comment: label: Summer '22
url: /services/data/v55.0
version: 55.0

Comment: You will have the instance in your company information under setup.

Comment: CS173 and CS102

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Salesforce only changed the domain for part of sandboxes, but not all of them.

While some sandboxes now have domain which includes `.sandbox` part, the other still do not have it, so it is required to manually go through each and every sandbox and figure out which has and which doesn't have this part and revert the change back

from

```
"https://company--qa.my.salesforce.com",
```

to

```
"https://company--qa.sandbox.my.salesforce.com",
```

for those who don't have `.sandbox` part in domain.

I understand that some of my sandboxes which are on preview instances, are already migrated to [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5), while the others on CS102 and CS173 did not.

I know that all production and sandbox environments will be upgraded to Winter '23 by October 17, 2022.

Comment: The addition of .sandbox is part of [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5), which will be enforced in Winter' 23.  The Sandboxes where it is enabled you will find .sandbox in the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [article](https://Salesforce%20enforces%20enhanced%20domains%20for%20sandboxes%20and%20non-production%20orgs%20in%20Winter%20%E2%80%9923%20if%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20postpone%20the%20enforcement%20using%20the%20My%20Domain%20setting.%20Salesforce%20enforces%20enhanced%20domains%20for%20production%20orgs%20and%20all%20remaining%20orgs%20in%20Spring%20%E2%80%9923.)

> Salesforce enforces enhanced domains for sandboxes and non-production orgs in Winter ’23 if you don’t postpone the enforcement using the My Domain setting. Salesforce enforces enhanced domains for production orgs and all remaining orgs in Spring ’23.

But the two instances which you shared CS173 and CS102 are not in Winter '23 they are still in Summer '22 Patch 18.23.

CS173 and CS102 will be Winter23 from October 15 you can check this in below [link](https://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS173/maintenances)